# Sorting events to show this week, month etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a list of events but I'm struggling to work out how to show specific date ranges in the index view.

I would like to list the events by showing events today, this week, this month etc.

I'm new to rails so I've tried to use this site and I've come up with the following which works for today's events.

```
@events_today = Event.find(:all, :conditions => ["date between ? and ?", Date.today, Date.tomorrow])
```

But I'm not sure how to set the page to automatically update and show only this weeks events and this month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic query should do something like this:

```
Event.where(date: date_range)
```

Now before calling this query you can set the date range variable. If you only want this week:

```
date_range  = Date.today.beginning_of_week..Date.today
Event.where(date: date_range)
```

Now there are all sorts of things you can do. You can select a start and end date or a custom period using either a form or a dropdown select. In this case date_range is set based on your params. You could also always use one predefined period.

If you want to work with several date range periods it could be nice to have a last_week, last_month, etc. scope in your model (or concern). Or you could simply define date_range constants in your initializers.

Comment: Good to hear. Could you upvote and accept my answer if it solves your trouble?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to show all the event of a week or month on click of tab 'Week' or 'Month' from view.

When you clicked on month or week for getting events, you send simply month or week in params(assuming params[:events_in] hold 'week' or 'month')

apply check on this attributes of params

```
def get_events_in_week_or_month
  if params[:events_in] =='week'
    start_date_of_time_period = Date.today.beginning_of_week
    end_date_of_time_period = Date.today.end_of_week
  else
    start_date_of_time_period = Date.today.beginning_of_month
    end_date_of_time_period = Date.today.end_of_month
  end

  #events in descending order
  @events = Event.where("date between ? and ? ", start_date_of_time_period, end_date_of_time_period).order("created_at DESC")

  #events in ascending order
  @events = Event.where("date between ? and ? ", start_date_of_time_period, end_date_of_time_period)
end
```

for getting more methods of date class, you should run following command on rails console :

```
 Date.public_methods
```